# How can I modify the basic Django template for SplitDateTimeField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a simple `SplitDateTime` field:

`meeting_datetime_start = forms.SplitDateTimeField(input_date_formats=["%a %d/%m/%Y"], input_time_formats=["%I:%M %p"])`

This renders the following HTML:

```
<input id="id_meeting_datetime_start_0" name="meeting_datetime_start_0" type="text">
<input id="id_meeting_datetime_start_1" name="meeting_datetime_start_1" type="text">
```

I am using bootstrap, and want to add a custom template to render this HTML differently, such as:

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
   <input id="id_meeting_datetime_start_0" name="meeting_datetime_start_0" type="text">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <input id="id_meeting_datetime_start_1" name="meeting_datetime_start_1" type="text">
</div>
```

How can I modify the basic Django template for the `SplitDateTimeField`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some possible solutions.

#### 1. Subclass SplitDateTimeWidget and redefine it's render method

By subclassing that widget you can inject into result code anything you want. After that just simply use your own widget with default SplitDateTimeField

#### 2. Create inputs in template by hand

Possibly simplest solution, but most ugly in my opinion. Create code in template by hand, using proper variables for name, id, value etc. You must add _0, _1 suffixes and format existing value by hand.

#### 3. Create template tag that will inject additional divs

You can create some template tag or filter that will do some text operations on default template to add additional divs.